# Enable/Disable deletefile option in FineUploader

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fine-uploader

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I want to know if it's possible to enable/disable the `deleteFile` option in FineUploader. I wanted that if the mode is in VIEW MODE, the user cannot delete the uploaded files. Only on EDIT MODE will the user be able to do so.

Here's my code for the initialization:

```
var uploader = $("#VEUploadFiles").fineUploader({
    template: 'TemplateManualTrigger',
    request: {
        endpoint: $("#UploadFilesUrl").val()
    },
    autoUpload: false,
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ["gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp", "pdf"],
        sizeLimit: 3000000,
        itemLimit: 5
    },
    deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        forceConfirm: true,
        method: "post",
        endpoint: $("#DeleteFileUrl").val(),
        params: {
            id: $("#UploadWithdrawFiles")
        }
    },
    callbacks: {
        onSubmitted: function(id, filename) {
            Util.ReorderFineUploaderList($("#VEFileUploadList"));
            $("#VEFileUploadList li:not(:first)").css("background-color", "#FFF");
        },
        onDeleteComplete: function(id) {
            Util.ReorderFineUploaderList($("#VEFileUploadList"));
        },
        onAllComplete: function(succeeded, failed) {
            if (failed.length < 1 && $("#UpdateStatus").val() == "UPDATED") {
                window.location.href = `${$("#DDRSummaryUrl").val()}/${$("#ProfileRowId").val()}`;
            }
        },
        onAllComplete: function(succeeded, failed) {
            if (failed.length < 1 && $("#UpdateStatus").val() == "UPDATED") {
                window.location.href = `${$("#DDRSummaryUrl").val()}/${$("#ProfileRowId").val()}`;
            }

            if ($("#UpdateStatus").val() == "VIEW") {
                // Test if the delete button will be disabled, but it doesn't even if there's a "disabled" attribute in the button itself.
                $("#VEUploadFiles .qq-upload-delete").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        },
    }
});
```

In one function, I will load all of the files that were uploaded to FineUploader:

```
uploader.fineUploader("addInitialFiles", uploadedFiles);
```

This is the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="TemplateManualTrigger">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div id="AttachFileButton" class="qq-upload-button-selector btn btn-primary">
                <div>Attach File</div>
            </div>
            <span><small>(jpg, jpeg, png, gif, pdf, Max 3MB)</small></span>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer-10"></div>

        <ul id="VEFileUploadList" class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list list-group" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <span class="fileIndex"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <button class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
                        </button>
                    <button class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
                        </button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

I tried to add using JQuery the keyword `disabled` in the buttons programmatically but I still get that alert when delete.

Hope you can guys help me with this.

Comment: create a working fiddle example link so that we can test and update you with solution

Comment: I will try to look for a template in JSFiddle to use. I'm not sure if it's possible to create one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can implement this based up on the criteria just set the enable option of  deleteFile section to true / false .

Comment: Not sure if I understand your suggestion. Does this mean that I would need to re-initialize the FineUploader plugin again?